# How to sync local directory with Amazon storage using aws s3api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

The local directory content can be sync with Amazon S3 storage using the following command:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket-0000002
```

Is there a similar command line available with `aws s3api`?
Thank you.

Comment: _Why_ do you ask?

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no sync capability with `aws s3api`.

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) provides access to the underlying AWS API calls, such as `aws s3api create-bucket` and `aws s3api delete-object`. Each of these calls map one-to-one with an AWS API call.

The `aws s3` commands are extra commands that only exist in the AWS CLI. They provide added convenience, making it quick to do things like create buckets (`aws s3 mb`) or delete an object (`aws s3 rm`).

Some commands, such as `aws s3 sync` have a great deal of added capability, which map to many API calls behind-the-scenes (eg listing objects, copying files, deleting objects).

So, basically:

- `aws s3api` maps to normal API calls
- `aws s3` provides additional functionality to make commands easier for users

Comment: is there an example to call aws s3 sync from aws s3api?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. The executable program is called `aws`. It then takes a "service" option, such as `ec2` or `dynamodb`. In the case of Amazon S3, there are two options available: `s3` and `s3api` as explained above. They are two separate options within the same program. There is no capability to "call" one from the other. What is the use-case that you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: there is no actual use-case. Just studdy. For example you can add the file to the bucket using s3 or s3api. You can rm bucket using s3 or s3api but there is no command in s3api to do the sync or to upload  file into bucket. I am just curious why some commands have the same functionality in  both servicers and some only in one.